# Is there any way to find undercuts from Autodesk Forge APIs?

Tags: javascript, java, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am making website which can find undercuts,volume ,x ,y,z coordinates from uploaded model in step format. I have got values of x,y,z and volume from model . I want to find undercuts no. Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: can you elaborate on your question? as of now, we cannot access the .step file, but translate into Viewer format or other formats. Not sure if I understood what you need...

Comment: I know about that . I just uploaded .step format file . Autodesk Api covert it into svf format and shows on viewer api. But my main task is to find volume ,x,y,z and undercuts . I found x,y,z and volume through viewer api extensions . But finding way for undercuts now.

Comment: ok, let me know if I can help then

Comment: Yes i need help. I am new to geometry and 3d world . If you can show me a way to do that it will very helpful for me.

Comment: we don't have a direct API for it, you may try with hitPoint function, but will take some geometry understanding.

Comment: Can you explain what is an "undercut", upload a screenshot or point to a link, then we can figure out what you are looking for. Thanks. Btw there is probably no direct way to identify a feature in the viewer as it only has knowledge about the geometry, so you need to use a pure geometric approach, for example to find a hole and this would require you to have a little knowledge about 3d geometry and how things works in Three.js...

Comment: The link of the model is http://123designs.biz/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/UndercutS.png....the green one labeled yes, is the correct way to model a part, there is no undercut that inhibits the 2 halves of the mold from seperating
the red one labeled red has a hole in the side, this part is not moldable with just 2 halves, the hole has no way of being filled with just 2 halves, a special moving part would need to be added
imagine the 2 halves of the mold, one on top and one on the bottom

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2GlIMkLrbs
this video quickly explains and has visuals

Comment: Any update guys.